# How can I bundle a person's info in a macro with genealogytree

Tags: tikz-trees, genealogytree

I would like to wrap each person's name and other information in a macro, and then use that macro in a genealogytree. This is to reduce clutter in the tree itself so as to make it easier to read and edit. But none of my attempts work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{mytree/.style={
    template=database traditional,
    database format=medium no marriage,
  }
}

\newcommand\nSon{name=Son, comment=Prince of the Valley}    % this does not work
%\newcommand\nSon{{name=Son, comment=Prince of the Valley}} % also does not work
%\edef\nSon{name=Son, comment=Prince of the Valley}         % also does not work
%\edef\nSon{{name=Son, comment=Prince of the Valley}}       % also does not work

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \genealogytree[mytree]{
    parent{
      %g{name=Son, comment=Prince of the Valley} % this works
      g{\nSon}                                   % this does not work
      p{name=Father, comment=King of the Hill}
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

Unless the package provides a way to pre-expand `\nSon`, you have to do it manually, with a bunch of `\expandafter`s.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{mytree/.style={
    template=database traditional,
    database format=medium no marriage,
  }
}

\newcommand\nSon{name=Son, comment=Prince of the Valley}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\tmpA{\genealogytree[mytree]}
\def\tmpB{parent}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tmpA
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\tmpB
\expandafter{%
\expandafter g%
\expandafter{%
\nSon}       %
      p{name=Father, comment=King of the Hill}
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Approach 2:**

Use `\expanded`, shown here with several macro insertions:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{mytree/.style={
    template=database traditional,
    database format=medium no marriage,
  }
}

\newcommand\nSon{name=Son, comment=Prince of the Valley}
\newcommand\nPar{name=Father, comment=King of the Hill}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\tmpA{\genealogytree[mytree]}
\expandafter\tmpA\expandafter{\expanded{%
  parent{%
     g{\nSon}       
     p{\nPar}
    }
  }}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't reduce the clutter!

Comment: @dedded No, it doesn't.  However, if you were to place it as part of a macro definition, the clutter would be confined to the document preamble.

Comment: But you've expandafter'd your way all the way back through the `\genealogytree` command.  How would you make a macro that doesn't dive down through the exact hierarchy of the tree?  Something that could be used for a "person" at any node in the tree.

Comment: @dedded As I am not a use of the package, I did't really anticipate the more general case for a larger tree.  But, perhaps there is a way with `\expanded`.

Comment: @dedded Please see my **Approach 2**.

Comment: It works some of the time. There is a mechanism in genealogytree for the `insert{}` of pre-defined sub-trees, and I can't get it to work within those.  It might not be worth pursuing this.

Comment: Accepting this answer, so as to not leave it open-ended, but I suspect a reasonable solution isn't really possible.  In the end I ditched genealogytree for my project and drew it manually in Tikz.